# Add to Database using flask-socketio

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I want to use flask_socketio to add realtime messaging function to my web. My website has a function in which messages are added to the messages table in my flask-sqlalchemy db. Now Im unable to understand how will I add a message to the database while at the same time posting it to the client server so it can instantly ne viewed, in easy words what flask-socketio is used for(instant update).The  function to add messages is:

```
@app.route('/<int:team_id>/<int:channel_id>/<string:channel_name>' , methods=["GET","POST"])
def channel(team_id,channel_id, channel_name):
*Irrelevant code*
 form = MessageForm()
 if form.validate_on_submit():
    message = Messages(msg_cntnt=form.msg_cntnt.data,msg_file
    =form.picture.data, sender_id=current_user.id)
            message.parent_channel = _channel_name
    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()    
messages = Messages.query.filter_by(parent_channel=_channel_name).all()
return render_template('team.html', _channel=_channel, team=team, channels=channels,
team_members_count=team_members_count, form=form, messages=messages)
```

I have tried a few ways of using flask socketio with it none worked. I also tried changing version of flask_socketio from 5.2.0 to 2 and then 4 but it didn't work. How can I achieve this? How can I add flask-socketio to it.
NOTE: In my team.html I have done:

Answer (score 0):

You could prioritize the realtime functionality first and saved it afterwards like this

```py
def save_message(msg):
  groupid = group.query.filter(group.groupid == msg["roomid"]).first()
  save = message(msg["sender"],msg["content"])
  db.session.add(save)
  groupid.message.append(save)
  db.session.commit()
  
  

@socketio.on("send_message")
def send_message(message):
  print(message)
  message["sender"] = current_user.username
  emit('add_element', message, to = message["roomid"], broadcast = True)
  save_message(message)
```

When "send_message" event is triggered then act like a normal emit message function, but after everything is done (transmission of real time message) then call a function that saves the message

Comment: But how manage it with the above route? I want this function to work on this route

Comment: Have you already implemented a socketio that automatically updates/emits messages from server to client and vice versa?